# How to subscribe to different telemetry data from Event Hub event readings routed from IoTHub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I have done research on the ways to subscribe to certain topics from EventHub (e.g. Temperature, etc.)

Initially we send messages from **Device to Cloud**  (e.g. from Device to IoTHub) using our **Client Application**, the device has some firmware configuration to **add telemetry data to message body** and Application Properties. The Client Application then will consume the EventHub **one endpoint.**

Since there are multiple types of telemetry data (Temperature, Humidity etc.). We don't really think reading each event from **one endpoint** is a good idea, although we can filter/process these data according to their **Application Properties**.

However, if we can have different threads to process from multiple **EventHub custom endpoints**, wouldn't that be more efficient.

What are the best solutions for these use cases ?

Answer (score 0):

In IoTHub you can use message routing.

> Filtering data before routing it to various endpoints by applying rich queries.

Ref: [Use IoT Hub message routing to send device-to-cloud messages to different endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c)